# R ggseasonplot: highlight the current year

Tags: r, plot, forecast

I have a time series object with monthly data over 20 years and used the ggseasonplot function form the forecast package to creat a seasonalplot:

```
ggseasonplot(x, polar = TRUE)
```

For better visualization I would like to highlight the data from the year 2019. For example by making the line for 2019 thicker than the other years.
Is that somehow possible?